# Detect if a different process runs a Metro application

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to detect from userspace if a foreign process (of which I only know its PID) runs a Metro application?

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately there's no other way to solve my problem. I seriously need to know if a process is allowed to draw windows in the Metro environment. Common Windows Store apps need to run in AppContainers, but that's not a reliable indicator, since any desktop application can voluntarily enter AppContainer to use it as a sandbox. For example the desktop Internet Explorer does this if you Enable Enhanced Protected Mode in Advanced settings. Also a desktop application may be allowed to display in Metro if it meets certain criteria (see "Developing a new experience enabled desktop browser" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465413.aspx). For example Chrome does this.

Comment: Perhaps explaining your use case will help others answer the question.

Comment: I've updated the question with all information I have available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there's an API function for this: [IsImmersiveProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Caveats include:

- explorer.exe, taskmgr.exe and possibly others are considered immersive for some reason
- you can only query processes running on the same [desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- some processes (e.g. bing maps' map.exe) start as non-immersive, and switch to immersive seconds later